# How to add a term to an optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling

There are several papers I read in which authors are dealing with an optimization problem and in most of the cases, they add an extra term to improve their models.
How can this be possibly done and everything still works perfectly ? or is it specific to the problem in hand ? or are there general rules that need to be followed in order to apply that ?

Here is an example: 
 $$\min_{D,C}\|Y-DC\|_F^2 $$
this model denotes for sparse coding, where D represents a dictionary to learn, C the sparse codes and Y the input vector, this is an unsupervised process, the term that was added is the following: $$\gamma J(C,L)$$ where J presents a penalty fucntion and L a matrix of labels. The equation becomes: $$\min_{D,C}\|Y-DC\|_F^2 + \gamma J(C,L)$$ in order to make the problem a supervised one.

Comment: Can you provide an example or two of what you're talking about?

Comment: You need to give an an example as your question is very broad. In some cases exact terms are replaced by approximations because they are easier to compute, in some cases the problem being solved is not precisely defined and terms are added to 'steer' the solution in some manner.

Comment: Are you talking about regularizations in regression problems?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I provided one, I hope it illustrates well what I was asking

Comment: Yes you are. What you are describing here is a regularization of the equation $Y = DC$ using the regularizer $J(C,L)$.

Comment: You can actually view it as a regularizer even if you're not used to think about it that way.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg: a regularizer isn't used to prevent overfitting ? Does trying to create a new model from a classic one by adding a loss function is similar to prevent overfitting ? note that $$J(C,L)$$ was proposed to be equal to $$ \|L-C\|_F^2$$, a linear prediction error, do we call that a regularizer ? 

(I am still new to this type of problems, giving a hint with what I can start would be highly appreciated.)

Comment: A regularizer can be used for many things as I write in my answer, such as preventing from overfitting. Generically, it is used to guide the solutions towards something we like (small amplitude, sparse, close to other solution). In your cause, you have a-priori said that you like solutions where $C$ is close to $L$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along the lines of the response from Johan, and a bit more related to your example of dictionary learning, you can easily see that the objective that you have without regularization is insensitive to scaling C and D inversely. This could cause a lot of problems for the optimization algorithm that tries to solve such a problem because one of the variables could explode and the other one could just go down to zero in terms of the size. So one natural way to prevent such scenarios is to regularize with the size of one of the variables which prevent such explosion and keeps the iterates of the optimization method bounded.

In general, the regularization terms try to encode the additional information that we have about the solution, which might not be captured by the metric (original objective). In the context of the above example, we might know that our final solution should be balanced in terms of the norm of C and D. Therefore, we try to limit the norm of those matrices.

In other cases you might know that your solution is going to be sparse. You can encourage your method to find sparser solutions by adding a "norm-0" regularizer that simply penalizes the objective for each non-zero entry. But such regularizer makes the problem intractable in general. Therefore, people have replaced such regularizer with a more well-behaved norm-1 regularizer for which there are some nice theoretical results in statistics literature regarding the recovery of the exact support of the true model (People use such norm-1 regularizer to promote sparsity even in the cases where there are no nice statistical recovery results).

So to answer your question in a nutshell: finding the right regularization for a problem requires a bit of intuition and would be very problem specific. But there are some general rules: when trying to add regularizers to a problem you need to make assumptions about the final solution that you want to recover. So you need to know the problem well. Then try to find a regularizer that can promote solutions with such behavior. Then, you need to make sure that the problem is still tractable with the chosen regularizer. One last step which is generally not easy is to choose the weighting for the regularizer, i.e. $\gamma$. People usually use a cross-validation scheme to find $\gamma$.

Answer (score 1):

Regularizations or penalty functions are commonly added to various fitting/regression/ML objectives in order to avoid overfitting/promote sparsity/reduce sensitivty to outliers.

Consider the trivial problem of fitting $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the objective $\|1-(x_1+x_2)\|_2^2$ (i.e. an over-parameterized problem). There are infinitely many solutions, and one optimal solution is for example $x_1 = 10^{100}$ and $x_2 = -10^{100}+1$. However, we do not like such solutions. Hence, we add a penalty on the size of $x$ and minimize $\|1-(x_1+x_2)\|_2^2 + \|x\|_1$ instead. An optimal solution now is $x_1 = 1/2$, $x_2 = 1/2$, or we could be lucky and obtain the sparse solution $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 0$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)